# Run .exe from same application space C++/C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have GUI (Winforms) connected to Dll. Clicking GUI controls changes Dlls internal variables. I also want to enable changing and accessing Dll internal variable via command line. **So, it is possible to start .exe within same process? For example like executing it as thread routine?**

I searched a lot and found out only things like this (in C#):

```
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = "Cmd_Interface.exe";
                Process.Start(startInfo);
```

But this starts new process with separate memories.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You want different executable seeing and changing the same data? Then call your executables clients. Take your dll and put it into a process you may call server and implement and interface for client-server communication.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, it is also solution. But for this I need to implement IPC, instead of using Dlls directly (I think this is little bit slower. And it is very complicated, changing structure of application.). I need only access it same like in case of multi-threading. I believe, this should be somehow possible, but I do not how.

Comment: You may want to be clearer in your question what you actually want. I don't see any connection between a seperate console client and multi-threading.

Comment: The question is, is it possible to run .exe inside the process, which called it (similarity with mutlithreading - creating new thread, accessing shared variables etc.)? I do not know, what is not clear on this question?

Comment: For example, there are a lot of applications in Windows forms, that allows users to open console and access it simultaneously with console and buttons ...

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: When your Cmd_Interface.exe is an assembly you can simply load it like any other assembly. The net framework does not distinguish between assemblies called exe or dlls that much. Then call the functionality you would have called via commandline parameters directly without using the console interface.